# PHP - Echo an array value from a class

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code

```
<?php
class SimpleEmailServiceMessage
{
    public function properNames($formValue) {
    $formValue = strtolower($formValue); //Make all letters small case
    $formValue = ucwords($formValue); //Make all first letters capital
    $formValue = str_replace('','',$formValue); //Remove extra spaces

    if(is_numeric($username)) {
      $error[] = 'The name is invalid';
    }
    return $error;
    return $formValue;
    }
}

$username = 'john doe';

$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
echo $m->properNames($username);

foreach($error as $result) {
    echo $result . '<br>';
}
?>
```

I am managing to output $username, but I am not managing to output $error[] if it is a number. $error[] in my case is an array as different classes will have an error.

The current code is telling me `Array Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /web/com/140895582016925/main.php on line 22` which is for `foreach($error as $result) {`

Comment: You get this error because `$error` does not exist (btw only in the function). The `return` keyword break your function. `return $formValue;` is never reached.

Comment: It should be `$e = $m -> properNames( $username ); foreach( $e as $result) ... `.

Comment: what is is_numeric? is it variable or a built in function? if variable put $ sign and if funnction then is_numeric($some_variable).

Comment: please notice your wong call to ``if(is_numeric) {`` that is a function you need ``is_numeric($value)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
   <?php
class SimpleEmailServiceMessage
{
    public $error;

    public function properNames($formValue) {
    $formValue = strtolower($formValue); //Make all letters small case
    $formValue = ucwords($formValue); //Make all first letters capital
    $formValue = str_replace('','',$formValue); //Remove extra spaces

    if(is_numeric($formValue)) {
      $this->error[] = 'The name is invalid';
    }
    return $formValue;
    }
}

$username = 'john doe';

$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
echo $m->properNames($username);

if(isset($m->error))
{
  foreach($m->error as $result) {
     echo $result . '<br>';
  }
}
?>
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/182951)**

Comment: @ins0 you may comment me if i am wrong. i am just updating my answer.

Comment: if was not so fast and then you deleted you answer so i couldn't :D

Answer (score 2):

The error message say it all: your $error is NOT an array.

Take a look at the is_numeric() validation part of your code.
You have an error there.
is_numeric() needs an argument.
In your case i think you need to:

```
if ( is_numeric($formValue ) )
{
// execute if condition
}
```

Comment: Hi, I adjusted the code to your update. Though the $error is an array as there will be multiple classes with the $error[]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use assignment:

```
$error = $m->properNames($username);
```

instead of `echo`ing:

```
echo $m->properNames($username);
```